# create new dataframe by finding swaped id in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe similar to following:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, "departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Pink","departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue"), (1, "departmentcode__10~#~p99189h8pk0__10484~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Black","departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue"), (2, "departmentcode__60~#~p99189h8pk0__10485~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon White","departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue"), (3, "departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue","departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Pink")], ["id", "left", "right"])
```

I need to create a new dataframe similar to following:

Here for id 0 and id 3 left and right got swaped, in that case, I need to create a new column named new_id, where new_id is the alternative id.
(for id 0, it is 3 and for id 3 new_id is 0. for rest it is null(iff no match found))

```
------------------+
|id |left|right |new_id
-+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0     |departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Pink     |departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue|3
|1  |departmentcode__10~#~p99189h8pk0__10484~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Black|departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue|null
|2  |departmentcode__60~#~p99189h8pk0__10485~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon White|departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue|null
|3  |departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue |departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Pink|0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a *left self join* but with following condition

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.alias('df1').join(df.alias('df2'), on=((f.col('df1.left') == f.col('df2.right')) & (f.col('df1.right') == f.col('df2.left'))), how='left')\
    .select(f.col('df1.id'), f.col('df1.left'), f.col('df1.right'), f.col('df2.id').alias('new_id'))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|id |left                                                                          |right                                                                        |new_id|
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|2  |departmentcode__60~#~p99189h8pk0__10485~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon White|departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue|null  |
|0  |departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Pink |departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue|3     |
|3  |departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue |departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Pink|0     |
|1  |departmentcode__10~#~p99189h8pk0__10484~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Black|departmentcode__50~#~p99189h8pk0__10483~#~prod_productcolor__Dustysalmon Blue|null  |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful